# C++ libraries for non-blocking, line-oriented socket I/O?

Tags: linux, sockets, select, nonblocking, epoll

I'm going to be writing a **Linux** client that will make a socket connection to five (or so) servers.  The client will send a "line" (a string followed by "\n") to each one, and will receive a line back from each one.

I'd like to use **select()** or **epoll()** in the client; however, this being TCP and stream-based, I'm not guaranteed to have an entire "line" in the system buffer when the **select()** pops.  What I'm looking for is a library that provides an API similar to **epoll()** and **sysread()**, but works on the basis of entire **lines** of data being buffered and ready to read.

I'm surprised not to have been able to find anything like this in my Internet searches - I would have thought this was a fairly common need.  (Maybe I haven't worded the problem correctly.)  It doesn't seem too difficult to write, but I'd suspect that an open-source solution would be more bullet-proof.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at boost [asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).  In particular it has a [`async_read_until`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until.html) function which does

> Start an asynchronous operation to read data into a streambuf until it
>   contains a delimiter, matches a regular expression, or a function
>   object indicates a match.

If you were using http I'd also suggest [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/0.9.4/index.html) which supports [asynchronous clients](http://cpp-netlib.org/0.9.4/reference/http_client.html).

Comment: That does appear to address my need, although I was hoping for something more parallel with select() or epoll().  May have to bite the bullet and learn asio.  (I'm not using http, btw.)

Comment: There's a bit of a change in mindset/architecture needed to move to a more event driven "handler"-based system.

Answer (score 1):

My [MUSCLE networking library](http://freecode.com/projects/muscle) provides this (via the [PlainTextMessageIOGateway](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/html/classmuscle_1_1PlainTextMessageIOGateway.html) class); it works well in my projects and it's BSD licensed so you're free to use it if you want.  The included [portableplaintextclient](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/muscle/test/portableplaintextclient.cpp) program in the tests subfolder is a very simple (94-line) example of how to use it.   The other respondents are right, though, that it's not too difficult to just write the necessary buffering logic yourself, either; but if you want a pre-written/pre-debugged solution, this is one.

Comment: Thanks.  Interesting to note, also, that you live about two blocks from me!

Comment: Do I?  I'm in Pasadena, CA; your info page says you're in Boulder, CO?

Comment: I see - then the address associated with MUSCLE is two blocks away.  // Oh! Never mind.  It was an ad.  >:-O

Answer (score -1):

There is no such thing. You need a buffer per connection and you need to read into it as dictated by select()/poll()/epoll() results until you have a line. These APIs don't care about line terminators like you do.

Comment: I know - I'm looking for 3rd-party solution.

Comment: @Chap I doubt that you will find one for such a trivial problem. It's only a few lines of code.

Comment: There was such a module elaborated in Lincoln Stein's "Network Programming In Perl".  It was more than a few lines of code.  I may have to revisit it and see what bells/whistles it provided, and translate to C++ myself if nothing similar exists.

Comment: As stated in the original question, I am aware that the system API doesn't know anything about line terminators, and I am looking for a layer/library/wrapper that *does* provide line-oriented, non-blocking I/O.  Your answer merely affirmed that the system doesn't provide this.

Comment: @Chap That is clearly not the case. I also told you how to implement it yourself, i.e. solve your problem. No 'merely' about it.

Comment: no offense intended!  But your answer didn't provide me any new information (you'll notice I *did* mention the need for buffering).  Perhaps it really is simple to roll my own, but often someone has come along and neatly handled other problems I hadn't thought of.